# Could not disconnect Visual Studio Online from the Windows Azure cloud service

Tags: azure, tfs

I am trying to disconnect my project from source control in TFS (in order to view the deployment history which I am unable to see due to **Get/Refresh TFS OAuth token failed with invalid_grant** error for which people have suggested to disconnect and reconnect the azure cloud service with TFS).

Any ideas how can I resolve this? I used to see the deployment history only few days ago and all of sudden I have started experiencing the above said error everytime I try to see the history past few days.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Paritosh

Comment: Similar issue, but different error message. I believe it was due to the Microsoft account used to authenticate between VSO and Azure had been disabled/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to access to `Section Administration TFS` in your `Web Portal`, and select `Administration` parts, you will have `Services Section`, enter in this section and deconnect `Azur Services`. `(You have link Disconnect)`

Comment: Can you please explain it bit more? I could not find an option for "Section Administration TFS" on the web portal....pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: you have on the right corner administration button  on your portal

Comment: For Visual Studio Online, the Url should look something like: https://youraccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_admin/_services